# Spring @Autowired bean not initialising; Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, autowired

Target.java:

```
package me;

@Component
public class Target implements Runnable {   
    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    public Target(){
        properties.getProperty('my.property');
    }

    public void run() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Config.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"me"})
public class Config {
    @Bean(name="properties")
    public PropertiesFactoryBean properties() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("src/my.properties"));
        return bean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        Target t = context.getBean(Target.class);
        t.run();
    }
}
```

With the above code. Bottom of stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at me.Target.<init>(Target.java:9)
 ....
```

Comment: `src/` can not be resolved, use `classpath:my.properties` instead.

Comment: That's not the issue.

Comment: when i walk through with the debugger the bean is successfully returned and I can query the property file when inside Config. The properties file is seen fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is called before properties is set. You are calling a method on properties in constructor before spring gets to set it. Use something like PostConstruct:

```
package me;

@Component
public class Target implements Runnable {   
    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    public Target(){}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        properties.getProperty('my.property');
    }

    public void run() {
      //do stuff
   }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You are doing field injection. You're referencing "to-be-autowired" instance variable inside constructor. In constructor, `properties` field is null because it has not been autowired yet. You can use constructor injection.

```
package me;

@Component
public class Target implements Runnable {   
    private final Properties properties;

    @Autowired
    public Target(Properties properties){
        this.properties = properties;
        properties.getProperty('my.property');
    }

    public void run() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```